# Leetcode 78 - Generate power set time complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, code-complexity

Leetcode 78 [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/) potential solution:

```
class Solution(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.map = {}
    
    def helper(self, count, nums, vals, result):       
        
        if count == 0:
            result += [vals]        
            
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            self.helper(count - 1, nums[i+1:], vals + [nums[i]], result)
        
    
    def subsets(self, nums):
        result = []
        result.append([])
        
        for count in range(1,len(nums)+1):
            self.helper(count, nums, [], result)   
            
        return result
```

For the above solution, will the time complexity be O(2^n) or will it be O(n * 2^n) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can find out the complexity by looking for different `N` how many times is the `helper` function called, code-wise would look like the following:

```
class Solution(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.map = {}
        self.counter = 0

    def helper(self, count, nums, vals, result):
        self.counter += 1
        if count == 0:
            result += [vals]

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            self.helper(count - 1, nums[i + 1:], vals + [nums[i]], result)

    def subsets(self, nums):
        result = [[]]

        for count in range(1, len(nums) + 1):
            self.helper(count, nums, [], result)

        return self.counter
```

So for:

| N | Time the helper function gets called |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 24 |
| 4 | 64 |
| 5 | 160 |
| 6 | 384 |
| 7 | 896 |
| 8 | 2048 |
| 9 | 4608 |
| 10 | 10240 |
| ... | .... |
| N | `O(n * 2^n)` |

The `helper` function has a complexity of `O(2^n)` and since you called for each element of the list `nums`:

```
for count in range(1,len(nums)+1):
    self.helper(count, nums, [], result)
```

the overall time complexity is `O(n * 2^n)`